# Ajax and filtering with multiple keys and values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a working version where I can filter through and display custom post types by meta_key and meta_value using the following:

This to loop through the values. I have 3 of these that I'd like to use

```
<?php foreach ($field['choices'] as $value => $label) : ?>
  <li><a class="js-filter-item" href="#" data-filter-value="<?php echo $value; ?>" data-filter-type="service"><?php echo $label; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The query

```
$service = $_POST['service'];
$level = $_POST['level'];
$location = $_POST['location'];


$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'cpt_listings',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key'    => 'service',
    'meta_value'  => $service,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

My js

```
var filter_type = $(this).data('filter-type')
var filter_value = $(this).data('filter-value')

    $('#js-filter').data(filter_type, filter_value)

    if (filter_type == 'service') {
        var ajax_data = {
            service: filter_value,
            action: 'filter',
        }
    } else {
        var ajax_data = {
            level: filter_value,
            action: 'filter',
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: wpws.ajaxurl,
        data: ajax_data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#js-filter').html(response);

        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.warn(response);
        }
    });
```

How would I bring this all together to use 3 options to filter the results? I've tried a few things online but they only chan(s).

Comment: I would probably _start_ by developing a different UI for this - because links aren't terribly suitable for _multiple_ selections to begin with. (You would either have to create individual links for each possible combination of all three(?) filter criteria - or to "keep track" of previously clicked links in your JS logic. And with the latter, having to click _several_ links in succession, probably isn't what most users would expect.) This should be a form with either checkboxes/radio buttons, or select fields.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I've marked it up like that so I can customise a select dropdown as only one choice will be selected from each of the filter options. These values are also populated from an acf front end form button group, so this route made a bit more sense to me.

Comment: If you want to allow only once choice from several options, then you can also use a radio button group. (And several radio button groups would still have the advantage, that you can query the selection for _all_ of them in one go - with links that get clicked separately, _you_ would have to "remember" the previous clicks for the other filter options in your code yourself somehow.)

Comment: I'm with you! I'll give that a go. Thank you.